# "Pomp" without "circumstance"

Tags: word-usage

Is the word *pomp* ever used without being followed by *circumstance*? It seems as though the word is only ever used to denote *pomp and circumstance*. Are there other uses?

Comment: Know of "pomp", but never even heard the phrase "pomp and circumstance" before.

Comment: Are you asking whether the word is used without the complementary "and circumstance"? Because it is perfectly ordinary to use it alone, as in [the solemn pomp of a military funeral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pomp).

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I've never heard of it alone. How odd.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment "Pomp and Circumstance" is a set of marches by the composer Elgar. You'll be familiar with the first one, I'm sure, since it's also the tune to "Land of Hope and Glory".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

From the past month's headlines:

> *Tim Tebow introduced by Jets, with pomp befitting a star, if not a starter*
>
> *Zimbabwe: Pomp, Fanfare As Book Cafe Reopens*
>
> *Pomp, pageantry and royalty at 15th Zik Prize Award ceremony*

Answer (score 4):

I've also heard it used in 'pomp and pageantry', 'pomp and ceremony', 'pomp and show' and 'pomp and pride'.

I've not heard it used on its own, though. These days we tend to use 'pomposity' instead.

Comment: *pomp and splendor* is another oft-used pairing. See also http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pomp+and+pageantry%2Cpomp+and+show%2Cpomp+and+pride%2Cpomp+and+splendor&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: One of wiktionary's example sentences for *[pomposity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pomposity)* mystifies me: "Your pomposity never ceases to astound me! Go do something unpleasant with a deer!"

Comment: @jwpat7 The results from searching for the phrase are even more mystifying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is, though it's much more common in its adjective form, *pompous*.

Answer (score 3):

In the Anglican and RC English rituals of Baptism, *pomps* (generic plural only) occurs frequently:

- .*.. that I should renounce the devil and all his works, the **pomps** and vanity of this wicked world, and all the sinful lusts of the flesh, ...*
- *I renounce Satan, and his works, and his **pomps**, and his worships, and his angels, and his inventions, and all things that are under him.*